# Vue.js Slug filter in link

Tags: vue.js

I've made a small `vue.js` filter and wraped it in a `_lodash` kebab-case to make my links SEO friendly when I pass restfull URL's like products/motor-bikes, however I can't wrap the filter within the binded href because it filters all of the url so I end up with products-motor-bikes. It applies the filter to the whole left side of expression.

How can I wrap my filter so it only applies to the binded value and not the string of products?

```
<a :href="'/products/'+motorbike.title+'' | kebab" class="c-sau-card__f-btn mt-3">Buy Now</a>
```

**The filter**

```
Vue.filter('kebab', function (string) {
 return _.kebabCase(string);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply a filter to only part of the expression; this calls for a method instead:

```vue
<a :href="`/products/${kebab(motorbike.title)}`">
```

```js
methods: {
  kebab: _.kebabCase
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to invoke a filter on only part of the expression then you can do this instead (although I don't recommend it):

```vue
<a :href="`/products/${$options.filters.kebab(motorbike.title)}`">
```

It's also worth mentioning that filters will be removed in the next major version of Vue (version 3), so I would avoid using them.

Comment: Yes, it's a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You can do it with `+` instead if you prefer.

Comment: You need to define a `kebab` method on the Vue instance like I have shown for it to be usable within the template. You can put it into a global [mixin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) if you want to use it across all Vue components.